# Loop in a promise [object, Object]

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I would like do an insert in my SQLite database for each article in my promise [object, Object], but it's not work when I try this :

```
    public saveAllArticles(allArticles): Promise<any> {
    this.createTables();

    return allArticles.toPromise().then(article => {

      console.log('SAVE');
      console.log(article);
      for (let a in article) {
      return this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO all_articles (' +
        'id,' + 
        'titre) VALUES ('
        +article[a].article_id + ','
        +article[a].article_titre + 
        ')', {})
    }}).then(() => {
      return this.db.executeSql('', {})
    })
  }
```

the parameter "allArticles" is an observable.

Code of createTables() :

```
    public createTables(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('ici');
    return this.db.executeSql(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS all_articles(' +
      'id INT PRIMARY KEY, ' +
      'titre TEXT)', {})
      .then(() => {
        return this.db.executeSql(
          'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles_by_category(' +
          'id INT PRIMARY KEY, ' +
          'titre TEXT)', {})
          .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

The console.log('Executed SQL'), console.log('SAVE') and console.log(article) are displayed, but I have this error after the console.log(article).

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at polyfills.js:3
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at o (polyfills.js:3)
>       at

The content of "article" is :

> (78) [Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, Articles, ...]

When I remove the return statement :

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: When you say: It does not work. What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Also is `createTables()` run in async?

Comment: no one to help me? :/

Comment: I don't believe you can have a return statement in your `for in` loop

Comment: Hi @LLai, how can I do ? I would like to insert my articles into my SQLite database and retrieve them when the user is not connected to the internet

Comment: Does your `this.db.executeSql` method work when you remove the return statement

Comment: No :/ I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Why not build your query string first, to be like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
 column1,
 column2 ,..)
VALUES
 (
 value1,
 value2 ,...),
 (
 value1,
 value2 ,...),
        ...
 (
 value1,
 value2 ,...);
```

and  then execute one query for inserting all articles?

```
public saveAllArticles(allArticles): Promise<any> {    
    return allArticles.toPromise().then(article => {
        let articlesQuery = [];
        for (let a in article) {
            articlesQuery[a] = '(' + article[a].article_id +  ',' + article[a].article_title + ')';
        }
        let queryString = 'INSERT INTO all_articles (id,titre) VALUES ' + articlesQuery.join(',');
        console.log('my query is: ', queryString);
        return this.db.executeSql(queryString);
    }  
}
```

Now you are returning a promise. I added a console log so now you can see if this is the right query.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I can try but what bothers me is that the query can not be dynamic, I'm wrong?

Comment: Try, it's dynamic and you build a query by theses dynamoc articles

Comment: Okay I try :) . I must delete let articles = []; ? It is inused ^^ and 
I suppose I must declare articlesQuery above the loop ?

Comment: public saveAllArticles(allArticles): Promise<any> {

    this.createTables();

    return allArticles.toPromise().then(article => {
      let articlesQuery = [];
      for (let a in article) {
        articlesQuery[a] = '(' +
          article[a].article_id + ',' +
          article[a].article_titre + ')';
      }
      let queryString = 'INSERT INTO all_articles (id,titre) VALUES ' + articlesQuery.join(',');
      console.log('my query is: ', queryString);
      return this.db.executeSql(queryString, {});
    });
  }

Comment: @ElGecko_76 oh yes it's articlesQuery not articles

Comment: I still have the error "Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]" :(, I have the query in the console.log but there is the error message

Comment: does the console.log query i put print the right query?